# get photo from iphone photo library and show in table view

Tags: iphone, xcode, alassetslibrary

I want to show all the images from the photo library in a table view. I am able to access all the images via assetsLibrary but unable to show them in table. I am not getting any kind of error but still don't know what is going on.

```
NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup   *group,  BOOL *stop){

         if(group != NULL){

        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

                if(result != NULL){
                [assets addObject:result];
                }else NSLog(@"NO photo");;
          }];
     }
}


failureBlock:^(NSError *error){NSLog(@"Error");}];
```

Datasource method for table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *identifier = @"id";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];  

if(cell == NULL){

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]thumbnail]]];

[cell textLabel].text = @"Photo";

return cell;
```

}

Pleaes help what i am doing wrong....

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer following link to solve your Issues

http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/tag/alassetslibrary/

Answer (score 1):

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
```

The lifetimes of objects you get back from a library instance are tied to the lifetime of the library instance.I added a static method to retrieve a shared instance of that class.

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {

    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;

    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    });

   return library; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

In above code add `__block` as follows:

```
__block NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```